# custom wp_editor does not save the content in plugin settings

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api, wp-editor

I am creating a custom settings page for my plugin. I have four textarea fields, Which need to be replaced by `wp_editor`. My problem is that I am not able to store the data to database. Bellow is my code.

```
add_settings_field( 
    'nga_textarea_field_2', 
    __( 'SMS templates', 'wordpress' ), 
    'nga_textarea_field_2_render_i', 
    'pluginPage', 
    'nga_pluginPage_section_4' 
);

function nga_textarea_field_1_render_i() { 
    $nga_textarea_field_1_invalid = get_option( 'nga_textarea_field_1' );
    error_log(print_r($nga_textarea_field_1_invalid,1),0);
    wp_editor( $nga_textarea_field_1_invalid, 'nga_textarea_field_1', array( 'textarea_name' => 'nga_textarea_field_1' )); 
    //update_option('nga_textarea_field_1_invalid', $content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be possible that your `wp_editor` is broken!
According to [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) you can not use numeric editor ID

> may only contain lowercase letters and underscores...hyphens will cause editor to not display properly

Call `wp_editor` in this way

```
wp_editor( $nga_textarea_field_1_invalid, 'nga_textarea_field_one' );
```

`textarea_name` is not required because by default it is already `wp_editor` ID.

I am not sure how you are saving the option but in settings API you need to pass the field name with `[]` for multiple fields with one option key.
e.g.

```
wp_editor( $nga_textarea_field_1_invalid, 'nga_textarea_field_one', array( 'textarea_name' => 'plugin_option_name["nga_textarea_field_1"]' ));
```

Where `plugin_option_name` is name of the option key which you've used in `register_setting`.

Comment: Im experiencing the very same thing. The odd thing is, when i switch from visual to text and save, then it gets saved, and vice versa. 
It's like the editor JS isn't registering the changes made until you trigger it by switching edit-mode.